# C++ DLL access in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to access functions from my C++ DLL using C# and am getting the error
`System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'BLib.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)'`

My C++ DLL code is

```
#include <sstream>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )

EXPORT class BLib {
    int testHTTP() {
        try {
            curlpp::Cleanup cleanup;
            {
                curlpp::options::Url authURL(std::string("https://example.com"));
                curlpp::Easy request;
                request.setOpt(authURL);
                request.perform();
                std::ostringstream os;
                curlpp::options::WriteStream ws(&os);
                request.setOpt(ws);
                request.perform();
                os << request;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch (curlpp::RuntimeError& e) {
            return 1;
        }
        catch (curlpp::LogicError& e) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
};
```

And i am trying to access this with the C# code

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace LibConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("BLib.dll")]
        public static extern int testHTTP();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling cURL");
            Console.WriteLine(testHTTP());
        }
    }
}
```

The program works if i remove the line calling `testHTTP()` i have read through multiple posts on a few different websites and could not find a solution that worked for me

Edit: Solved the original problem now getting the error `System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'testHTTP' in DLL 'BLib.dll'.`

Comment: "or one of its dependencies" is surely the root cause.  While the code as posted can never work, there's some likelihood that the curl module is not found.  The C++ runtime is another candidate, but tends to be available on a dev machine.  Use the C# project's post-build event to xcopy the DLLs that you need.

Comment: Create a simple C++ console application that does only `HMODULE h = LoadLibrary("Blib.dll");`.  After that line of code, is `h` NULL?  If so, then work on why a regular C++ application cannot load the DLL, and not focus on C#.

Comment: Move `EXPORT` to the function, not the class. And you need `[DllImport("BLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl)]` But neither of those will fix your issue. To be brutally honest, why would you ever want to do this, when C# has `HttpClient`?

Comment: I need to do this as this is not the only function that would be added to the dll there will be more that need to be made in C++ as they are not in C#

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie alright i tried what you suggested and yes `h` was NULL

Comment: I managed to solve the problem of the dll not loading turned out libcurl.dll and zlib1.dll were missing but now getting a new error "System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'testHTTP' in DLL 'BLib.dll'."

Comment: As @Charlieface mentioned above, you should "EXPORT" the function `testHttp` not the class enclosing it.

Comment: I tried that and when i do i get random errors like `syntax error: 'string'` on line 13 (the line where `testHTTP()` is defined) and `unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body` again on line 13 then i also get 4 `the managed nullptr type cannot be used here` errors from a file called `exception` on lines 278,283,291 and 295 then another error `linkage specification is not allowed` on line 13

Comment: `extern "C"` cannot be applied to classes. You should export some global functions, and these global functions can work with classes.

Comment: Whenever i remove the class or only export the function then it gives around 11 errors

Comment: Removing the class and exporting just the function gives the errors [here](https://prnt.sc/ldjWv90-3_gM) and exporting the function inside of the class and not exporting the class gives the errors [here](https://prnt.sc/dD_WpcfZgV-q)

Comment: Just looked and the errors `the managed nullptr type cannot be used here` are always present and do not seem to interrupt the build process

Comment: You are left with linker errors, which means you fixed all compiler errors. You reached the next level, congratulations. In this case you have to add curl library to C++ project. Google for LNK2020 and LNK2001.

Comment: Alright its all working now thanks for all the help everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly like the error says, either your dll is missing or one of its dependencies is (anything from the runtime, to the debug runtime if you try to do illegal things, the curl dynamic library if you didn't link it statically, etc etc).

Also to pre-empt the obvious answer, no, just because you have a dll in some random folder that you like doesn't mean it exists from the point of view of a particular process.

Comment: The DLL is in the folder where the C# executable is saved and cURL is imported using the lib file from vcpkg and has the correct include and dependency directories setup and also the runtimes that are needed are all installed

Comment: Another possibility would be that the dll isn't the same architecture as the application

Comment: Both of the projects are set to build for x64

Comment: @XPlyr Use a tool such as Dependency Walker to see what the dependent DLLs are for `BLib.dll`.

Comment: Dependency Walker has been unresponsive for 20m now

Comment: Use https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies, Dependency Viewer doesn't work in modern OSs anymore. And it can't be the architecture, you get another exception for that (`BadImageException`). And I will say it again, just because you put it in a folder you like (in this case, "in the folder where the C# executable is saved") doesn't mean it can find it.

Comment: There are 0 missing dependencies

Comment: Also updated the path in the c# app to be absolute and it still gives the same error

Comment: The error is happening on line 13 where it is calling `testHTTP()`